# Invalid syntax django

Tags: python, django, imx6

I'm trying to run a django code an imx6 yocto build that i made. The basic example went fine and smooth. So i decided to run my own django production from a project im working and i get the following:

```
root@imx6ulevk:/home/mdwb-main# python manage.py runserver 147.106.17.9:8000  
Watching for file changes with StatReloader  
Exception in thread django-main-thread:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner  
    self.run()  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run  
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper  
    fn(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in   inner_run  
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in   raise_last_exception  
    raise _exception[1]  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute  
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper  
    fn(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup  
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate  
    app_config.import_models()  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models  
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)  
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module  
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 985, in _gcd_import  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 693, in exec_module  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 799, in get_code  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 759, in source_to_code  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed  
  File "/home/mdwb-main/api_cloud/models.py", line 15  
    return f'{self.cloud_interval} foi cadastrado com sucesso!'  
                                                              ^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code in models.py is the following:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Initial_config(models.Model):
    #complement = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    cloud_interval = models.IntegerField()
    device_interval = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'config'
        verbose_name_plural = 'configs'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.cloud_interval} foi cadastrado com sucesso!'
```

I tried to change the *'* to *"* remove the {self.cloud_interval}, but none of them was sucessful.
Why this happens? How to fix it?

Comment: f-strings (like `f'{self.cloud_interval} ...'`) aren't supported in Python 3.5. These were first introduced in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

`f-strings` can only be used from Python 3.6 onwards.

If you want to remain with Python 3.5, you can change your code to:

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s foi cadastrado com sucesso!' % self.cloud_interval
```

That said, Python 3.5 is no longer officially supported; upgrading to 3.6 or above is highly recommended. See https://endoflife.date/python for more.

Comment: Yep, this help a lot, i upgraded Python and now the program is running fine. Thx a lot guys